# Spring Batch: testing using Mock instead of @JobScope bean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-batch

How can I replace `@JobScope`'d bean with `Mockito` mock?

I was trying following approach:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, JobScopeTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyBrokenTest {

  @Autowired
  public ValueObject myJobScopedBean;

  @Test
  public void doStuff() throws Exception {
    myJobScopedBean.setVaue(new TestObject());
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("myCoolTasklet", getJobExecution().getExecutionContext());
  }
}
```

but no success. Within step new value of `myJobScopedBean` is not initialized. As far as I understand that `JobScopeTestExecutionListener` is not intended to be used together with `jobLauncherTestUtils`, is that correct? How can I test my steps with mocked dependencies?

UPD.

Configuration as also straightforward:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {
  /* ... Job definition ... */

  @Bean
  @JobScope
  public Tasklet getMyCoolTasklet(MyJobScopedBean myJobScopedBean) {
    return new MyCoolTasklet(myJobScopedBean);
  }

  @Bean
  @JobScope
  public MyJobScopedBean myJobScopedBean() {
    return new MyJobScopedBean();
  }

}
```

Comment: We'd have to see how your bean is being defined, but you'll want to override the real (job scoped one), with your mocked one.

Comment: @MichaelMinella i've updated question. So the only way to override it which i have found - provide additional `@Configuration` with MyScopedBean which will override another one... But this looks ugly

Comment: You are correct.  We'd expect you to provide an additional `@Configuration` with the beans you need to override.